# Qt Creator "too big" on 3840x2160 and 150% scaling on Windows 10

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator, hidpi, qt5.10

I installed Qt 5.10 SDK on Windows 10. I thought that the HiDPI issues were fixed in Qt 5.6, but Qt Creator still seems to be "too big":

[image]

Am I missing something? My resolution is 3840x2160 with the "recommended" 150% scaling. Visual Studio in the background is of the correct size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably has its own hidpi functionality, unlike the legacy windows stuff that's just a direct upscale, so it appears to look bigger on your display which is amplified by the scaling you have applied.

From the information [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) it seems that you can go about to either set a custom scale factor or a custom DPI awareness scheme.

You can set those as system environment variables or use some cmd basic scripting to set them at a per application level:

```
@echo off 
set QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
qtcreator.exe
```

Comment: Yeah, setting environment variable `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5` solved this issue. However this is not something that the end user should do..

Comment: That's a side effect of Qt being portable - it has to work on platforms that have no notion of hidpi and platforms that supports it natively. Qt has supported "default" hidpi for some time - that is it attempts to look the same regardless of the DPI, which means things are actually larger on hidpi monitors, and when you add 150% scaling on top of that it becomes exaggerated. It will probably look OK without any scaling, but since the windows shell doesn't support hidpi it will look too small.

Comment: It works partially. Some parts of qtcreator are already scaled to 1.5 by Gnome, some parts aren't. If I use `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5`, then some parts are scaled 1.5 times, and other parts (menu and status bar for example) are scaled 2.25 times. Besides that, icons are crunchy and some lines in the theme are 1 pixel or 2 pixels at random.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus you should file a bug report, especially if the other answer didn't work neither.

Answer (score 17):

I guess the default `HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy` of QtCreator is `Round`. so you can only scale to 1 or 2 not 1.5.

The correct solution is set the environment variable:

```sh
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY=PassThrough
./qtcreator.exe
```

Comment: THIS is the correct answer. Qt supports high DPI scaling in Windows for a while now, it even uses that code path, it is only that it rounds the detected DPI to an integer. Thus, on Windows with 3840x2160 with 150% scaling it shows the UI scaled at 2x. Setting that environment variable alone solved the issue. Run "sysdm.cpl" -> Advanced - > Environment variables and "New" (either user, either system, your choice), name: "QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY", value: "PassThrough". In a batch script, you do "set QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY=PassThrough". Thanks @Bob Brown for the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with the nextcloud-client on Windows 10 and a scaling of 150%, solved by

(a) setting a global enivronmental variable in Windows 10 called *QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY* with the value *PassThrough*:
[Windows-dialogue for setting variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0dEW.png)
You can do so by hitting the Windows-key and search for *variables*...

or
(b) a batch-file containing:

```
@echo off
set QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY=PassThrough
start C:\path\to\nextcloud.exe
exit
```

and then starting that batch-file. *(Of course you have to adapt the path to your actual nextcloud.exe location.)*

[If you want this to be run on startup, hit the keys windows and r , enter shell:startup and leave a link to your batchfile in the now opened folder. (Deactivate "run at startup" inside the Nextcloud-App to be sure the batchfile really runs.)]

(a seems to be more convinient for me.)